# OpenGL wgl center text

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, mfc

I am drawing text in an OpenGL context under Windows, with the following helper function, I got ir from http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/ :

```
GLvoid glPrint(HDC hDC, const char *fmt, ...)                   //Custom GL "Print" Routine
{
char        text[256];                              // Holds Our String
va_list     ap;                                     // Pointer To List Of Arguments

if (fmt == nullptr)                                 // If There's No Text
    return;                                         // Do Nothing

va_start(ap, fmt);                                  // Parses The String For Variables
vsprintf_s(text, fmt, ap);                      // And Converts Symbols To Actual Numbers
va_end(ap);                                         // Results Are Stored In Text

glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);                          // Pushes The Display List Bits
glListBase(base - 32);                              // Sets The Base Character to 32
glCallLists((GLsizei)strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text); // Draws The Display List Text
glPopAttrib();                                      // Pops The Display List Bits
}
```

I position the text by calling

```
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
glRasterPos2f(0.f, 0.f);
```

before `glPrint`, where `x`, `y`and `z`is the point coordinates where I would like to center my text.

This draws my text starting on the bottom-left corner. How can I center this text on its own centroid?

I tried `GetTextExtentPoint32` to position my text, as follows

```
SIZE extent;
GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, SpinTools::string2wstring(text).c_str(), strlen(text), &extent);
glRasterPos2f(-extent.cx / 2, -extent.cy / 2);
```

but this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you idea with GetTextExtentPoint32 was right. But this futnction returns value in screen space, you need to convert it to [-1..1] sapce. You can try this code: glRasterPos2f((float)-extent.cx / (g_width), (float)-extent.cy / (g_height)); g_height and g_width are size of window

Comment: if you know size of each letter you can get with and height of all letters. When it will be done you can set position for raster. Also position of rasters depends of camera position, projection and current transform.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the size of each letter?

Comment: I think you idea with GetTextExtentPoint32 was right. But this futnction returns value in screen space, you need to convert it to [-1..1] sapce. You can try this code: glRasterPos2f((float)-extent.cx / (g_width), (float)-extent.cy / (g_height)); g_height and g_width are size of window.